# Save VisualStudio 2013 item templates in different folders

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to organize the item templates in different folders so that they will be visually separated in the "Add New Item"-Window in some way?
Just like "Windows Forms" and "WPF" templates are visually separated in the "Add New Item"-Window.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx), templates can be visually separated by placing them in different folders. This could be done easily in the WindowsExporer.

Additionally you have to close all instances of Visual Studio and restart it to see the changes.